# How to inject javascript variable in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, width

I have two js variable both are getting the value from server, and i want to use these values to set the width on client side in '%'.

```
const x= 20;
const y = 40;

<div  style={{"width" : `{ parseInt(x) / parseInt(y) * 100 + "%"}` }} className="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" >
```

{ parseInt(x) / parseInt(Limit.y) * 100 + "%"} Completed

But this is not setting the width.

Comment: What are the `parseInt()`s for? `width: x / y * 100 + "%"` is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style={{ width: `${(parseInt(x) / parseInt(y)) * 100}%`, backgroundColor: "red" }} className="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
   hello
</div>
```